# VPS not accessible

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface, ovh

I don't have access from outside the machine.
Can someone help me plz

Best regards

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: that picture of the symptoms doesn't help cure a problem you created

Comment: How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by commenting this line in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
#       post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

I will apply `iptables` rules later.

Comment: Nice =) And welcome to the community.  Please note that SE communities aren't discussion forums. An answer is posted that resolves the issue - [even if the answer is your own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) - is noted simply by [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get a handle on how the community works.